# invalidFileSizeMessageDetail & invalidFileSizeMessageSummary messages are not visible for p-fileUpload component

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the p-fileUpload component of PrimeNG.

Code Snippet:

***<p-fileUpload #uploadFiles name="myfile[]" mode="advanced" (onSelect)="handleCustomUpload($event,accordionIndex,item)"
multiple="multiple" (onRemove)="handleRemove($event)" invalidFileSizeMessageSummary="{0} has wrong size, "
invalidFileSizeMessageDetail="it exceeds {0}." maxFileSize="1000000">***

However, When I am selecting a file which exceeds the maxFileSize, that file is not selected but I am not able to see the invalidFileSizeMessageDetail or invalidFileSizeMessageSummary

In few places, it is mentioned that the mode should be **advanced** but after changing that also it is not working.

Can anyone please help me with this problem.